# Slow tab switching in Vim with large terminal

Tags: linux, vim, editor, terminal

My vim is very slow to switch tabs (`:tabnext`) when i've fullscreened my terminal (1920x1200).

Does anyone have a fix for this? Is it a vim issue, or is it my setup? Redrawing a black terminal (gnome-terminal) with a bit of text shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably the gnome-terminal problem. Vim with my fullscreen (1920x1080) rxvt-unicode (urxvtc) terminals works just fine.

Comment: Correct. Switched to urxvt and used http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/how-make-urxvt-look-gnome-terminal/ to make the transition easier. :)

Comment: Can you clarify what "the gnome-terminal problem" is?

Comment: @LondonRob No idea. But when Vim switches to the next tab it redraws entire screen which puts higher then usual load.

Comment: @Zyx but redrawing a single screen of console window shouldn't take a noticeable amount of time should it?

Comment: @LondonRob Have you ever worked with `<C-A-F1>` non-framebuffer terminal? This depends purely on implementation. I know that vte-based terminals are sometimes reported as slow and I know that Vim has to redraw the entire screen when switching tabs. I can’t say that it’s exactly what culprit is, but it seems to be the most likely problem, especially given the fact that tabs were introduced in vim-7.0 when Vim was usually used in faster terminal emulators (so less requirements were put onto code drawing efficiency). You can write a “Hello World” which eats 100% CPU for a few minutes if you want.

Comment: @LondonRob I am wrong: slow `<C-A-F1>` I saw in GRML, and GRML uses framebuffer.